# Laravel dispatching Queues at set time

Tags: laravel, scheduling

I am currently dispatching queued jobs to send API Events instantly, in busy times these queued jobs need to be held until overnight when the API is less busy, how can I hold these queued jobs or schedule them to only run from 01:00am the following day.

the Queued Job call currently looks like:

```
EliQueueIdentity::dispatch($EliIdentity->id)->onQueue('eli');
```

there are other jobs on the same queue, all of which will need to be held in busy times

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use delay to run job at a certain time.

```
EliQueueIdentity::dispatch($EliIdentity->id)
    ->onQueue('eli')
    ->delay($this->scheduleDate());
```

Helper for calculating the time, handling a edge case between 00:00 to 01:00, where it would delay it a whole day. While not specified how to handle busy, made an pseudo example you can implement.

```
private function scheduleDate()
{
    $now = Carbon::now();

    if (! $this->busy()) {
        return $now;
    }

    // check for edge case of 00:00:00 to 01
    if ($now->hour <= 1) {
        $now->setTime(1, 0, 0);
        return $now;
    }

    return Carbon::tomorrow()->addHour();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use delayed dispatching (see https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/queues#delayed-dispatching):

```php
// Run it 10 minutes later:
EliQueueIdentity::dispatch($EliIdentity->id)->onQueue('eli')->delay(
    now()->addMinutes(10)
);
```

Or pass another carbon instance like:

```php
// Run it at the end of the current week (i believe this is sunday 23:59, havent checked).
->delay(Carbon::now()->endOfWeek());
// Or run it at february second 2020 at 00:00.
->delay(Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', '2020-02-02'));
```

You get the picture.